# Using subset() to select ranges of data

Tags: r

I am new to R functions, always preferred to use packages and avoid loops. However, now I am trying to create a loop for a specific question that I have. I would like to subset a dataset based on ranges. I think the code below is self explanatory.

```
dt = as.data.frame(sample(1:100))
names(dt) = "num"

subs.it <- function(x) {
     subs <- subset(dt, num >= (x - 5) & num <= (x + 5))
     return(subs)
}
subs.it(c(15, 50))
```

wrong output:

```
    num
44   55
47   20
65   19
77   17
83   12
91   16
92   51
100  54
```

correct:

```
   num
4   15
18  11
47  20
50  13
54  10
65  19
66  14
77  17
82  18
83  12
91  16
17   48
19   53
29   45
33   52
39   46
44   55
45   50
49   49
89   47
92   51
100  54
```

I can't find what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You are essentially requesting all `x >= c(10,45) & x <= c(20,55)` which is just nonsensical from R's perspective. Probably you mean to have two conditions joined by an "or", like `(x >= ... & x <= ...) | (x >= ... & x <= ...)`?

Comment: what do you suggest to do?

Comment: to subset the dataset based on ranges. I will have more than one number. For example when the number is 15 to subset from 10 to 20, and when number is 50 to subset from 45 to 55. The final dataset to have ranges of numbers from 10 to 20 and from 45 to 55.

Comment: I outlined exactly what to do at the end of my comment

Comment: Joran it was not clear for me. How you will write this `subs <- subset(dt, num >= (x - 5) & num <= (x + 5))`

Comment: I honestly don't know how else to write it. I basically wrote it down exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the function you are looking for is `subset` itself. Try:

`subset(dt, num > 15 & num <50)`

**edit:**

ah I see you want two different ranges. You can do this:

`x = 15
y = 50
subset(dt, (num >= x-5 & num <= x+5) | (num >= y-5 & num <= y+5))`

or a more compact version using absolute values:

`subset(dt, (abs(num - x) <= 5 | abs(num - y) <= 5))`

Comment: thanks, but it doest work. I need ranges of numbers based on condition above. So i need to get numbers from 10 to 20 and from 45 to 55.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
set.seed(12345)

library(dplyr)

subs.it <- function(x, y, z) {
      subs <- x %>% filter(
        (num >= (y-5) & num <= (y+5)) | (num >= (z-5) & num <= (z+5))
                     )
      return(subs)
    }


subs.it(dt, 15, 55)

    num
1   16
2   14
3   15
4   55
5   52
6   17
7   56
8   13
9   57
10  54
11  18
12  53
13  11
14  58
15  19
16  10
17  51
18  60
19  20
20  50
21  12
22  59
```

Comment: Thanks. In example above i showed only 2 numbers (15, 50) but in my real data will be many more, about 30 numbers. Basically, I want to subset a dataset from a range of values. I have certain values (i.e 15, 20) and based on those i want to subset rows with value +/- 5.

Comment: So add additional variables to the function, not just y and z, maybe aa, ab, ac.. ap etc. Keep adding variables accordingly.

Comment: I'm unsure if there's a way you can create a for loop that will append variable range filters as you are asking.

Comment: you are correct. Now I think I will call the numbers one by one (i.e. 15) and then will create another functions to merge all the datasets I create from subset.